# Can't add a Generated Column

Tags: mysql

I have a Price column (DECIMAL 6,2) in my MySQL Products MyISAM table and I'm trying to add a Generated Column to multiply it per 2. I'm trying to use this:

```
ALTER TABLE Produtos ADD COLUMN Price_double DECIMAL(6,2) AS (Price*2);
```

But I'm getting this in HeidiSQL:

> Error SQL (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'AS (Preco*2)' at line 1

I don't know what to do. Really...

My MySQL's version is 5.5.51-38.2

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?  Your syntax should be working.

Comment: This feature is only available in MySQL 5.7 or later (q.v. [here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-generated-columns/)).  It won't work.

Comment: Oh, I see. I'll try to update it. Thank you =D

Comment: Add it as an answer!

Comment: I have added an answer below per your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL only supports generated columns in version 5.7 or later, q.v. the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html):

> As of MySQL 5.7.6, CREATE TABLE supports the specification of generated columns. Values of a generated column are computed from an expression included in the column definition.

However, you syntax appears to be correct, and if you were running 5.7 or later you should not see any error.

For a workaround to using a computed column, you can just compute the product in the `SELECT` statement in your PHP code.  Keep in mind that there is overhead to having *any* column in your table, including a computed one.  And if you are not sure that you will be needing the computed amount frequently, you could argue against altering your table in the first place.

Comment: Are you still there? I can't update and I don't want to create a view for just one column... Any suggestion?

Comment: Well if you were using MySQL from an app layer, such a Java, I would tell you to just compute the column in your `SELECT`.  Would this be an option for you?

Comment: Well, I'm using PHP. It is a solution, but it will make my code a little complicated hahahaha

It's a good idea. Thank you!